# Unable to send mail using XAMPP SendMail

Tags: php, sendmail

I trying to send a mail using PHP mail function but unable to do and getting below messages in debug file:

> --- MESSAGE BEGIN --- 15/09/23 09:13:49 ** To: xyz@gmail.com 15/09/23 09:13:49 ** Subject: the subject 15/09/23 09:13:49 **  15/09/23
>   09:13:49 **  15/09/23 09:13:49 ** the message 15/09/23 09:13:49 ** ---
>   MESSAGE END --- 15/09/23 09:13:49 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
>   15/09/23 09:14:02 ** Disconnected. 15/09/23 09:14:02 ** Disconnected.
>   15/09/23 09:14:02 ** Disconnected. 15/09/23 09:14:02 ** Socket Error #
>   11001Host not found.

For this, I have installed ZAMPP v3.2.1 on Windows7.

And made following entries as:

php.ini-

```
SMTP= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 587 
sendmail_from = my gmail id 
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

I downloaded a latest sendmail folder and did these settings in that. Also I tried to use 25 port and SMTP as localhost but they also did not worked.

sendmail.ini-

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mygmailid
auth_password=mygmailpassword
```

Tried with ssl, auto etc but did not worked.

Also tried by setting compatibility of send Mail executable file with 'Run as admin' but in that case it needs a acceptation prompt on my machine and if I accepts that then it returns some value in my mail function and I got response as 'Mail Sent' but in actual mail also not received.

Comment: Have you tried port 465 (SSL)?

Comment: No not used 465, I am using 587 with tls to get mails in my mail box

Comment: With 465, getting same problem.

Comment: Did you download the most recent XAMPP version (not sure about 3.2.1) from here: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.12/)?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded latest XAMPP version which is xampp-win32-5.6.12-0-VC11-installer

Comment: In php.ini you only need `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`. I do not know the correct connection settings for Gmail (you should be able to find/check them somewhere online), but you can try to set `stmp_ssl=ssl` and `smtp_port=465`.

Comment: I tried and its not working. :(

Comment: Make sure that you are using the whole email address as user name and try it again, if that does not work either, set `smtp_ssl=tls` with port 465.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following extensions enables php_sockets & php_smtp

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell more about them, How can I check them?

Comment: have you referred this link http://toknowtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2012/12/smtp-configuration-in-xampp-server-to.html

Comment: These extension are automatically enabled in XAMPP package (if they are needed for mailing).

Comment: @Aashi, which mailer api you are using?